# CheckStyle doesn't warn in case of missing JavaDoc on methods

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

My CheckStyle configuration looks okay according to the [documentation](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_javadoc.html#JavadocMethod) but it seems I missed something because it does not warn me if JavaDoc is missing front of a public method.

My configuration warns me if the JavaDoc is missing from the class, but I want to be warned if the JavaDoc is missing from any public methods as well.

Example class:

```
/**
 * Say something.
 */
public class Kkkk {
    public void aaaaa() {
    }
}
```

My CheckStyle configuration:

```
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
        <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
        <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
        <property name="allowedAnnotations" value="Override, Test"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing a parent [<module name="Checker">](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config.html#Modules)?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Everything is in between "Checker". Maybe I overwrite these settings later, somehow? But I only have one "JavadocMethod" section.